# stop timer (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

how can i stop a timer after one time?

thanks

Comment: There are at least four different timers in .NET, so which one are you talking about?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the timer event should only execute once ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume by timer you mean the Windows Form element Timer.  So if I'm wrong feel free to disregard this.

The best way to have it only go off once is to have it turn its own .Enable false at the end of the function.  Thus any time it is enabled, the timer will function as normal, until it goes off then it will disable itself until the next time it is enabled.

Hope this helps!